# Logging in Angular2

Tags: angular, logging, error-logging

Is there any framework for logging actions in Angular2. I would like to have debug, error, info logs. Previously I used NLog framework but it doesn't support Angular 2. Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's something [here](https://www.bennadel.com/blog/3138-creating-a-custom-errorhandler-in-angular-2-rc-6.htm) that may help scratch that itch

app-module.ts

```
@NgModule({
providers: [
        ErrorLogService
           ]
})
```

Write your own ErrorLogService

Or [this](https://github.com/code-chunks/angular2-logger)

Answer (score 0):

I know this is a little late, but following is a worthy logger for anyone looking out for logging options in Angular:

[NGX Logger](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ngx-logger)

Advantages :

1) Customizable to log at any levels : ['TRACE',
  'DEBUG',
  'INFO',
  'LOG',
  'WARN', 
  'ERROR',
  'FATAL',
  'OFF']

2) Customizable to log in server using : 'serverLoggingUrl'

3) Gives Pretty Print to the console

4) In conjunction you can use, splunk ( or any other tracking tool) to track any logs/issues.

5) Customizable to send custom HttpHeaders/ HttpParams, which really helps in usecases like sending metadata.

Cheers (y)